# How to fix "Invalid Add-on" error when installing unpublished Gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I developed a Gmail addon on my personal Google scripts workspace. I didn't have any trouble installing it on my personal Gmail. I haven't published it to the app marketplace yet and I wanted to install ([using this method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished)) it on my company's Google Suite email account (I am the administrator of that Google Suite account). However, when I copy the deployment ID and press install I get an error saying "invalid addon".

[image]

I have made sure that:

1. My work email account has read access to the google scripts folder with the code
2. Security preferences allow third party marketplace apps on the

Any guess on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's just not possible to instal an unpublished add-on across different domains without making a new copy of the add-on's code.

Answer (score 1):

In company GSuite email account, it is not possible to install a developer add on(developed from personal gmail account) as GSuite company accounts are more secured.
There is a way we can whitelist the add-ons in GSuite admin console, but they did not add it for developer add-in yet.

I encountered the same problem for my company's GSuite account. I followed the following steps to solve the issue:

1. Share the developer add-on from personal account to GSuite email account.
2. Login to GSuite email account.
3. Open Google drive by navigating to https://drive.google.com
4. Here you can see the add-on shared from your personal account, make a copy of this.
5. Open the new add-on, take the deployment id of this new add-on and install in your gsuite gmail.

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed a solution, except I want to install it this addon in multiple domains (different Google Suite accounts) and I did not want to have multiple copies of the add-on code that I have to update everytime I make a change to it. 

It seems that (at  the moment) you can create an add-on in a gsuite account and install it on a personal gmail, but you cannot install a developer add-on from one gsuite account to another (meaning different domains).

Comment: Thanks a ton! You made my day!

Comment: How did you take the deployment id ?