# How to install a developer add-on to another Gmail account?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have developed a simple Gmail add-on, I have Published it using a manifest.
Finally, I got "Get ID link for the Head Deployment", from this development id I have installed it to my current Gmail account, it is working perfectly. The problem was by using development id; we need to use it on another Gmail account, but I have followed same steps [install-unpublished gmail addon](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished)
but it is not working.

Updated:
      i have installed other account also,check ss
[image: install]

but when i open email doesnt appear my addon

[image: doesnt appear my addon]

**Update-2**
[image: install addon ss]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it "doesn't work"? What actually happened? If you got an error, post  it and the error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @ChrisW check my updated details

Comment: On the [Install Unpublished Addons page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished) it suggests "checking the **Enable debugging information** checkbox. If selected, any errors the add-on script encounters cause the add-on to automatically display an error card to the user." Have you tried doing that and are you getting an error?

Comment: @ChrisW where is that checkbox, Optionally, check the Enable debugging information checkbox.i cant saw that checkbox,while install addon

Comment: It should show up when you install the addon. Try removing and when you re-install look for that option.

Comment: @ChrisW i have tried  with the checkbox,I trust the developer of this add-on.check my above ss

Comment: Have you tried sharing the Google Drive/App Scripts project with the desired account? If you are getting a "Invalid add-on" on the settings screen this is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Gmail add on, when we install the developer add on for the first time. The add on is not showing up for the existing emails.

I faced the same issue. I dont know why it is happening like that, as per my observations, add on is not showing up for the mails which are sent/received before my add on is developed/installed.

**Send some new emails and go to sent box, open the new mail which you sent and check for the add on. It should work. It worked for me.**

**Prerequisites:**

1. The add on has to be shared to the other gmail account from the
   owner of the app script.
2. The add on can not run in Gsuite email account which was developed from personal gmail account. To solve this, I answered in one more post: [Getting "Invalid Add-on" when installing unpublished Gmail addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48918803/getting-invalid-add-on-when-installing-unpublished-gmail-addon/48943249#48943249).